# Tangent spaces and local approximations of manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'm approaching differential geometry from a physicist's perspective in the hope of understanding GR more thoroughly.

I've been told that, intuitively, the tangent space $T_{p}M$ to a point $p$ on a manifold $M$ is "*the best linear approximation to the manifold $M$ at that point*". What is meant by this?

Is it meant in the sense that the tangent vectors at that point provide the best linear approximation of functions on the manifold at that point? Does this extend for a sufficiently small neighbourhood around a given point?

In the context of GR, is this a mathematical implementation of the equivalence principle, in the sense that the $T_{p}M$ is *flat* and so the laws of physics are those of special relativity (SR) on $T_{p}M$. The laws of physics on $M$ are therefore SR for a sufficiently small neighbourhood of $M$ around a given point?

Comment: I don't think "best linear approximation" is a good description of tangent spaces. If it is the best, then there should be some worse linear approximation. Then what are those? And how do we formulation good approximation in the first place without a metric? If a manifold is not embedded in some Euclidean space, I don't think there is such "best linear approximation".

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2512008/meaning-of-the-differential-of-a-map-between-manifolds-as-an-approximation

Answer (score 3):

> I've been told that, intuitively, the tangent space $T_{p}M$ to a point $p$ on a manifold $M$ is "the best linear approximation to the manifold $M$ at that point". What is meant by this?

This statement is meaningful if your manifold is embedded in an higher dimensional Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. It is very much like a linear tangent to a $1D$ curve. For example, see this illustration from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space) of a tangent plane to a sphere

[image]

Lets look at manifolds embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. If, for example, you can write your manifold as $z=f\left(x,y\right)$ around $p$, and you expand this function into its Taylor series

$$z=f\left(x,y\right)\approx f\left(p\right)+\nabla f\left(p\right)\cdot\left(\left(x,y\right)-p\right)+\dots$$

then

$$z=f\left(p\right)+\nabla f\left(p\right)\cdot\left(\left(x,y\right)-p\right)$$

is the tangent place. $T_{p}M$ is this plane as a vector space.

> In the context of GR, is this a mathematical implementation of the equivalence principle, in the sense that the $T_{p}M$ is flat and so the laws of physics are those of special relativity (SR) on $T_{p}M$. The laws of physics on $M$ are therefore SR for a sufficiently small neighbourhood of $M$ around a given point?

Yes. It means that by changing coordinate system at a point, your metric can be transformed into the Minkowski metric $\eta_{\mu\nu}$.

Comment: I've been told that there are two different approaches though: 1. One uses Riemann normal coordinates on the manifold, such that the laws of physics reduce to their SR form within this coordinate chart. Physics is however, only approximately SR within this chart since the metric is only exactly Minkowski at the origin of the coordinate chart...

Comment: ...2. One can work directly in the tangent space choosing coordinates on $T_{p}M$, in which physics is exactly SR, since the metric is globally Minkowksi on $T_{p}M$. Since the tangent space at a point approximates the manifold near that point, the physics is approximately that of SR near that point.

Comment: I think your physics question suits https://physics.stackexchange.com/ more. You should ask it there.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll ask that part of it there.

Answer (score 3):

This interpretation is not a good one when we talk about manifolds from a intrinsic point of view (i.e., not embedded in Euclidean space), and understanding the intrinsic point is part of the requirements and power of differential topology and also GR.

One good point of view is the following:

Suppose you are at a point $p$ on a manifold: imagine the surface of the Earth, for instance. How would you be able to distinguish directions intrinsically, using only information from Earth itself? You can try looking at the curves passing through $p$. There are some which are obviously distinct from the others in terms of directions, but there are some which may be getting very close to themselves. They are not equal as curves, but it seems like they are "tangentially" equal. Well, now you are in trouble, because if you wanted to measure if they are tangentially equal or not directly, you would need to know what are the "geometrical" tangent vectors: an information which you may not have. You could, if you knew you were inside an Euclidean space, but the fact is that you don't. What now?

Let's be more primitive about what we mean by **directions**. Our view of *tangents* is fairly intricate if you think about it. Let's discard it for a while. Imagine you and me are at the point $p$, and then we agree to start moving. I feel that it is getting hotter, and you feel that is getting colder. Well, certainly, whatever definition of direction we use, this should mean that we've gone to different directions. Now let's come back to the point $p$, and start moving again. This time, we did not sense such a difference on heat, but instead on pressure. We must have gone different directions again. Heat, pressure etc are all things intrinsic to Earth. This idea may go somewhere.

Now, let's take a small leap of faith: we propose, as inhabitants of the Earth, that there are sufficiently many measurements (heat, pressure etc) that we can do in order to fully distinguish directions.

Let's mathematize the discussion above. We are at a point $p \in M$. A measurement is a smooth function $f:M \to \mathbb{R}$. We are following curves $\gamma: I \to M$ such that $\gamma(0)=p$. Now, my curve then determines an object $D_{\gamma}$ which takes the measurements and give me how they are varying when I go through $p$, i.e., it is an object of the form
$$D_{\gamma}: C^{\infty}(M) \to \mathbb{R}$$
$$f \mapsto (f \circ \gamma)'(0). $$
This is, **by definition**, a tangent vector: the operator $D_{\gamma}$.

And you can check that there are sufficiently many smooth functions on the manifold $M$ to guarantee that we can distinguish the tangent space as a $n$-dimensional vector space as expected.

Comment: Is there a way in which one can locally approximate the manifold with the tangent space though, analogously to how the tangent space to a point on a sphere locally approximates the sphere within a sufficiently small neighbourhood of that point?

Comment: @user35305 No. Your statement can be made intelligible if you restrict to: "If $M$ is a smooth **submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n$**, then the tangent space is the best linear approximation etc etc". But please, read this answer with more solicitude. You seem to have grasped to an intuition which, if you don't let go eventually, may hinder your progress on the understanding of the general setting (which is maybe one of the cornerstones of the theory: to be able to talk about things like curvature without needing to be embedded somewhere).

Comment: How could one fit the idea of differentials of functions between manifolds in this interpretation? $\text{Given } F: M \rightarrow N $ and differential $(dF)_p:T_p M\rightarrow T_p N$
a "direction" $(dF)_p (\gamma)$ would be the direction in $T_p N$ in which measurements
$g\in C^\infty (N)$, change the same way that 
$g\circ F\in C^\infty(M)$ change in direction $\gamma$. Which I can't get to make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

The following is not really a mathematical answer, but here we go anyway, to clear up some misconceptions.

There is no such thing as "laws of physics on $T_pM$ are those of special relativity", for the following reason. The vectors in the space $T_pM$ is only supposed to give you some directions to point towards. The actual spacetime is just the manifold $M$. More precisely, assuming you already know what an event (a point in $\Bbb R^4$ spacetime) is in the context of special relativity, an event in the context of general relativity is a point on the manifold $M$. The vectors/points on $T_pM$ are not events by definition.

The following statement is one I am not even sure about (I haven't really studied general relativity/pseudo-Riemannian geometry yet). You should ask an expert to double-check.

Since there is the notion of curvature in GR but not in SR (or more precisely, the curvature in SR is simply zero everywhere), it cannot be the case that laws of physics on a small open set in $M$ is the same as those of SR unless the curvature on the small open set is zero.